# Google Analytics UA: Zero Hits but multiple users

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

within my Google Anayltics UA-driven site I have that overview on data with zero hits on all pages but multiple users/new users/time on page - see screenshot. [image]

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this data from the last couple days?

Comment: Nope. That is data of the last 30 days